# How to match up the corners of 2 different lines in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I have two lines at different angles and I want to get a corner from each line to be in the exact same position.  Here's a visual:

[image]

The general problem is that I'd like these two lines to appear perfectly flush and and joined.  Maybe there is a better overall way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Join the end anchor points of the paths creating a corner, if that's
   what you want. (`Object > Path...`)
2. Expand the strokes to shapes then using the Direct Selection tool,
   line up the sides of the shapes. (`Object > Expand...`)
3. At times, setting the end caps of the strokes to rounded (in the
   Stroke Panel) will make the strokes *appear* to connect. This is not
   always a solution since end caps cna easily overlap other strokes.

Answer (score 0):

Select both lines or points, Go to "Stroke" and press on Round CAP and Round Corner, if the lines not match perfect, expand them -> Unite and delete undesirable anchor points